# The constructor of an RAZOR page never gets called in my Blazor project

Tags: .net, razor, blazor

The constructor NOR any methods (OnGet, OnPost...) are called in my razor page.
I did try even with an  to test it out but neither succeeds in fire a method.

Thanks in advance !!

Here are my classes concerned :

Login.cshtml

```
@page
@model Pages_Identity_Login
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Log in";
}
<h3>Login</h3>
<form method="get">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Login.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace BlazorCatAPI.Pages.Identity
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        public LoginModel()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ALLOL");
        }
        public IActionResult OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = "")
        {
            string provider = "Google";
            // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
            var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Page("./Login",
                pageHandler: "Callback",
                values: new { returnUrl }),
            };
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, authenticationProperties);
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            string s = "ALLO";
            OnGetAsync();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCallbackAsync(
            string returnUrl = "", string remoteError = "")
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var GoogleUser = User.Identities.FirstOrDefault();
            if (GoogleUser.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    RedirectUri = Request.Host.Value
                };
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new ClaimsPrincipal(GoogleUser),
                authProperties);
            }
            return LocalRedirect("/home");
        }
    }
}
```

And the component from where I called the Login page
LoginControl

```
@using System.Security.Claims
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor
@inject HttpClient Http

@if (User.Identity.Name != null)
{
    <img src="@Avatar" />
    <b>You are logged in as: @GivenName @Surname</b>
    <a class="ml-md-auto btn btn-primary"
       href="/Identity/Logout"
       target="_top">Logout</a>
}
else
{
    <a class="ml-md-auto btn btn-primary"
       href="/Identity/Login"
       target="_top">Login</a>
       
}


@functions {
    private ClaimsPrincipal User;
    private string GivenName;
    private string Surname;
    private string Avatar;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();

        try
        {
            // Set the user to determine if they are logged in
            User = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;

            // Try to get the GivenName
            var givenName =
                _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User
                .FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName);

            if (givenName != null)
            {
                GivenName = givenName.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                GivenName = User.Identity.Name;
            }

            // Try to get the Surname
            var surname =
                _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User
                .FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname);

            if (surname != null)
            {
                Surname = surname.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                Surname = "";
            }

            // Try to get Avatar
            var avatar =
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User
            .FindFirst("urn:google:image");

            if (avatar != null)
            {
                Avatar = avatar.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                Avatar = "";
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

I do expect to the Login page to fire the OnGetAsync(...) method to be able to redirect to the distant google url that is stocked within 'appsettings.json'.

All of this to be able to permit a user to sign in my app with his Google account

Comment: try changing `@model Pages_Identity_Login` to `@model BlazorCatAPI.Pages.Identity.LoginModel` in  `Login.cshtml`

Comment: Why are you mixing RAZOR and BLAZOR together?

Comment: Ok the change of the model did work !!
Thanks a lot man !

As for why I'm mixing RAZOR and BLAZOR, I'm just trying to have Google Auth in my app and all examples are with RAZOR. I will translate it into Blazor when it's working .

Answer (score 0):

The razor page `Login.cshtml` needs to know what `PageModel` it needs to use for its model.

`Login.cshtml`

```
@page
@model BlazorCatAPI.Pages.Identity.LoginModel // declare the correct PageModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Log in";
}
<h3>Login</h3>
<form method="get">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

However, I agree with @Jimmy Kurian, it's recommended to use blazor(`.razor`) components not razor(`.csthml`) components.